# How to check whether two lines are going through middle together in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

[image: screenshot of the indicator]

I have a Pine Script, where I measure volume flow with two lines with different length. The length of the white line is approximately 40, the length of the green line is approximately 130. I want to know (put a label for now), where green and white lines go through the middle (zero) together. The sample points where the lines go together are mentioned by red vertical line for shorts and green vertical line for longs. The yellow vertical line shows the point where green and white lines are not going synchronous (together) through the middle.

So, in my case the white line is called vfinal and green line is named vfinal2.

I tried to write something like:

```
    var int mode = 0
    
    if (vfinal[1] > 0 and vfinal < 0)
        mode := 1
    
    if (vfinal2[1] > 0 and vfinal2 < 0 and mode == 1)
        lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_label_down, text = "Sell", textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal, color = color.blue)
```

However, this method doesn't look whether the white line went through the middle before or not. I need these two lines to go synchronously through the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [ta.cross](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcross)

Something like that:

```
if ta.cross(vfinal, 0) and ta.cross(vfinal2, 0)
    lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_label_down, text = "Sell", textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal, color = color.blue)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help. The thing is that I need to monitor lines before they go through the middle. I should be looking for vfinal2 and vfinal going down from positive values. So, if vfinal and vfinal2 go through the middle, I need to be sure that the lines are going next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could have it has ta.crossunder instead of ta.cross to check if they're both coming down from positive values.

```
if (ta.crossunder(vfinal, 0) and ta.crossunder(vfinal2, 0))
    lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_label_down, text = "Sell", textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal, color = color.blue)
```

And if you want to make sure that they haven't crossed before in X bars you can have this and add a "and not" condition to the above code for it.

```
var bool crossed1 = false
var bool crossed2 = false
if (ta.cross(vfinal, 0))
  crossed1 := true
if (ta.cross(vfinal2, 0))
  crossed2 := true
```

Example implementation of the above:

```
if (ta.crossunder(vfinal, 0) and ta.crossunder(vfinal2, 0)) and not crossed1[1] and not crossed2[1] and not crossed1[2] and not crossed2[2] and not crossed1[3] and not crossed2[3]
    lab = label.new(x = bar_index, y = 0, yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_label_down, text = "Sell", textcolor = color.white, size = size.normal, color = color.blue)
```

There's probably a more efficient way to accomplish it but this should hopefully help get you started.